# Naturally ban wrapper classes in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

So, I found it more natural to work in algorithms with collections, not with pair of iterators. So, I wrote some functions like

```
template <typename R>
void sort(R& range) {
    return std::sort(std::begin(range), std::end(range));
}
```

And to have possibility to work with parts of collections I've wrote following wrapper class, that just holds pair of iterators.

```
template <typename T>
class Range{
public:
    Range(T begin, T end): begin_(begin), end_(end) {}

    const T& begin() {
        return begin_;
    }

    const T& end() {
        return end_;
    }


private:
    T begin_, end_;
};
```

To that point all is fine. Now I want to have function that copies/(moves if possible) its argument and return new collection.

I wrote something like this:

```
template <typename R>
R sorted(R range) {
    sort(range);
    return std::move(range);
}
```

and that's fine except that if I call it with my wrapper `Range` class internal collection changed. I do understand that with only iterator type it's generally impossible to retrieve the type of collection to create new one, but I want to at least disallow calling it with this Wrapper.

**I do understand** that I can use `static_assert` of `enable_if` to check if it is of particular `Range` class and I will do that way unless I will find better way. But I want ban it somehow in more general way, so that similar implementation will fail to compile too.

Any ideas?

Comment: You could disallow implicit copying your ranges...

Comment: @Deduplicator, I thought about making range move-only, but that will not help with `sorted(Range(begin, end))` because just move is needed.

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/range/doc/html/index.html

Comment: Well, you could typedef a `is_wrapper` member in your wrapper ranges and SFINAE out `sorted` if that type exists... somewhat more general than just checking for `Range` the particular class.

Comment: I experimented with something like this but decided it's not worth the hassle to fight against how the standard library wants to be used. Good luck though.

Answer (score 2):

You can delete the function like:

```
template <typename T>
void sorted(const Range<T>& range) = delete;
```

else you can disallow copy and move of the object, so it can only be used with reference

```
template <typename T>
class Range{
public:
    Range(const Range&) = delete;
    Range(Range&&) = delete;

    Range& operator =(const Range&) = delete;
    Range& operator =(Range&&) = delete;

    // previous code
};
```

Answer (score 2):

I would create a traits class called `owning_container`.  By default it considers arguments that are ranges (you should have a traits class/concept constexpr for that -- if `begin(x)` in a namespace with `using std::begin;` returns an iterator, call it a range) and have an allocator (another trait) to be owning (as non-owning ranges usually have no need for an allocator) as well as C arrays and `std::arrays` as owning (via specialization).

This also allows me to detect rvalue owning containers and move their contents in certain contexts (change their iterators into `move` iterators) without doing the same to non-owning range views.

As mentioned above, a `constexpr` pseudo-concept might be better than a traits class, or might be useful to augment it.

Comment: `std::array` has no allocator. OK, it's not really a Container either.

Comment: @dyp yep -- handle that and C arrays via specialization.  I forgot.